# laravel pass id to controller and display name and phone number in url

Tags: php, laravel

I have table contains `id`, `name`, `city` and `phone_number`, I want to use `id` to return some data from controller and want to show only the `name`, `city` and `phone_number` in url like this way:

```
Endpoint: GET /store/sushi-chicago-7736159912/
```

and from this controller to pass id to controller to return some data

```
 Route::get('store/{id}','FrontController@getStoreProducts');
```

Comment: You want to redirect */store/sushi-chicago-7736159912/* URL?

Comment: but instead of / whant -

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store - create and `sushi-chicago-7736159912` is slug, it`s my opinion =)

Controller code:

```
public function getStoreProducts(string $slug)
{
   $explodeSlug = explode('-', $slug);

   $product = Product::where(['name', $explodeSlug[0]])
        ->where(['city', $explodeSlug[1]])
        ->where(['phone', $explodeSlug[2]])
        ->first();
   if (is_null($product)) {
       //throw exception
   }

   return $product
}
```

Route:

```
Route::get('store/{slug}','FrontController@getStoreProducts');
```

Or you may use another way:

Edit route:

```
Route::get('store/{id}/{slug}','FrontController@getStoreProducts');
```

Edit method in controller:

```
public function getStoreProducts(int $id, string $slug)
{
   //in this way you don`t use slug

   $product = Product::where(['id' => $id])
        ->first();

   return $product
}
```

And now your urls will looks like

> /store/41/sushi-chicago-7736159912/
>
> /store/41/sushi%20bar-chicago-7736159912/

Comment: its working if i put it like this 'store_id'=>$explodeSlug[3]], but the problem if the store name has space between its part like cafe crisp? how to put - between them and in the same way can I add id to phone number? like this

store/Cafe%20Crisp-chicago-77360640-1
I want to merge 1 to the phone number and to replace % with -

Comment: @Glove i think this is very bad idea, you need use id (1,634, 21) or slug with strict pattern. `-` or  ` ` or something else is wrong way to build application

Comment: you mean I have to use just id and not to use the slug? ok but I need to display the url in that way how can I do this

Comment: yes please update this ['id'=>$id], Now before make it correct do you think now is it good use what you updated for building apps?

Comment: @Glove done. I think this way is not ok, but this is the best in your situation =)